# extract sub sequence Python

Tags: list, python-3.5, subsequence

Question:

Given a sequence of numbers, extract the sub-sequence of maximum length which is in ascending order.

Example input: `L = [1,3,5,6,1,5,1,6,7]`

Output: `[1,3,5,6]`

Code:

```
def Sequence(integers):


sequence = []
i = 0
stored = []
#newseq = []

for i in range(len (integers)-1) :

    if integers[i] <= integers[i+1]:   #i less than i+1 append to sequence
        stored.append(integers[i])
        sequence.append(integers[i])

    else:
        if integers[i] >= integers[i+1]:

            del sequence[:]

    if len(stored) > (len(sequence)):
        print('biggest subseq =',stored)
        print('small sub',sequence)

print (stored,sequence)

Sequence([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5])
```

Error:

It is outputting `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4] [1, 2, 4]`

But it should be outputting: `[[1, 2, 3, 4,5] [1, 2, 4, 5]`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> once this works I can display the biggest subsequence. any ideas?

My idea is that it won't work, you need to rewrite it quite a lot.

You start by looping through the numbers (`for i in ...`), which is great, and the first `if` test picks up a run of increasing numbers, OK so far. But then you add the numbers to both `stored` and `sequence`. Why add the same thing to both?

Then the `else` triggers if the sequence stops increasing. That's cool, you can follow an increasing sequence and notice when it ends. But you don't trust that, and you do the exact same test again with another `if`, because ... reasons? There, you delete `sequence`. "*I'll track all the sequences, and when they end, I'll throw them away without using them because throwing away the things I'm looking for is just fine :)*".

OK, from the names you've given things, I guess `sequence` should be "*the current sequence I'm working on*".

After those `if` tests, for every loop iteration, you check `len(stored)`; `stored` never gets cleared or reset, so it just builds up almost every number in the original list. Once you do that length test ... you do nothing, except print things.

What you print: `print('biggest subseq = ', sequence)` - makes it look like the name `sequence` is supposed to be the "*biggest*", but that's wrong compared to the way you used it earlier. `sequence` is not the biggest one, it's the current one, right? Or not right? "*I'll use unhelpful names, because I don't like typing long names. Why isn't my code working?*". Yeah, I do that all the time too.

Then you print that `stored` is the 'small sub'? What's a small sub? Whatever it's supposed to be, `stored` isn't holding anything useful at this point.

And, the way you are tracking numbers `i >= i+1` and only adding `i` to sequence when it matches, means you always miss the last number in every sequence. ("the next one is smaller, so I'll skip adding this one").

and worse than that, the way you are tracking `range( len(integers) - 1)` means you never check the very last number in the original list into the final subsequence.

So yeah, a simple fix won't work for your code. It's going along the right lines for a workable answer, but it's completely not doing the right things to actually do it.

---

I think what you're trying to do is "track along until a sequence ends, and store it. Then, find the next sequence. If that is longer than the previous stored one, store the new one instead". So:

1. Give yourself clear variable names that explain what they are for.
2. In `stored` you should be setting it once to the entire sequence you've found, not adding individual numbers to it as you see them.
3. That needs to happen at the point where the sequence ends, not for every number in the input list.
4. That means the update for `stored` needs to happen inside `if len(stored) > len(sequence)`.
5. .. which needs to test the other way - is the new one longer than the stored one.
6. And it needs to take an action to update the store.

Trying to write that, as close to your code as I can, gets me this:

```
def Sequence(integers):

  longest_sequence = []
  current_sequence = []

  for i in range( len(integers) ):

    if i < len(integers) - 1 and integers[i] <= integers[i+1]:   # sequence continues
      current_sequence.append(integers[i])
      print('current_sequence ', current_sequence)

    else:                           # else sequence, or input, ends now
      current_sequence.append(integers[i])   # catch this last number in sequence, too
      print('\nsubseq ended ', current_sequence)

      # now we've hit the end of a subsequence
      # do we replace the stored one, or not?
      if len(current_sequence) > len(longest_sequence):
        print('\nreplacing previous longest ', longest_sequence)

        longest_sequence = current_sequence

      # either way, reset the current sequence tracker
      current_sequence = []

  print()
  print ('Finished. Longest found: ', longest_sequence)


Sequence([1,2,3,4,5,1,2,4,5])
print('\n----\n')
Sequence([1,2,4,5,1,2,3,4,5])
```

Which you can [run online at repl.it here](https://repl.it/E7yl/1).